# "Comparison Method violates its general contract" - even with correct implementation of comparator

Tags: comparator

I have some problem with the collection.sort() method.

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Comparison method violates its general contract!
>
> at java.util.TimSort.mergeLo(TimSort.java:747)
>
> at java.util.TimSort.mergeAt(TimSort.java:483)
>
> at java.util.TimSort.mergeCollapse(TimSort.java:410)
>
> at java.util.TimSort.sort(TimSort.java:214)
>
> at java.util.TimSort.sort(TimSort.java:173)
>
> at java.util.Arrays.sort(Arrays.java:659)
>
> at java.util.Collections.sort(Collections.java:217)

this is my comparator

```
public int compare(Key key1, Key key2)
{

    if (key1.Score > key2.Score)
        return -1;

    else if(key1.Score < key2.Score)

        return 1;

    else

        return 0;
}
```

I am currently jdk 1.7, i tried with 1.6 also but it did not work. I am not able to understand whether it is the problem with sort method or some other issue.( I am trying to sort a list with more than 1000 items and it does not have any NaNs).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Violating the general contract of a comparison method means that it does not provide a consistent or correct answer. It seems this method does not return the same result while comparing the same objects for several times.

This code works fine as a standalone version. Do you have some other threads modifying the collection items?